# While migrating panva / node-oidc-provider package in nestjs from version 6 to 7.11 getting error 'interaction session not found'

Tags: node-oidc-provider, oidc-provider

hi i am getting interactions and sessions created in mongo collection. however i am getting below error.

````
    at resumeAction (/app/iam-authorization-server-microservice/node_modules/oidc-provider/lib/actions/authorization/resume.js:28:11)
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
    at async sessionHandler (/app/iam-authorization-server-microservice/node_modules/oidc-provider/lib/shared/session.js:29:5)
    at async noCache (/app/iam-authorization-server-microservice/node_modules/oidc-provider/lib/shared/no_cache.js:3:3)
    at async authorizationErrorHandler (/app/iam-authorization-server-microservice/node_modules/oidc-provider/lib/shared/authorization_error_handler.js:53:7)
    at async ensureSessionSave (/app/iam-authorization-server-microservice/node_modules/oidc-provider/lib/helpers/initialize_app.js:50:7)
    at async contextEnsureOidc (/app/iam-authorization-server-microservice/node_modules/oidc-provider/lib/shared/context_ensure_oidc.js:4:5)
    at async /app/iam-authorization-server-microservice/node_modules/oidc-provider/lib/helpers/initialize_app.js:245:5
    at async errorHandler (/app/iam-authorization-server-microservice/node_modules/oidc-provider/lib/shared/error_handler.js:26:7) {
  allow_redirect: true,
  error: 'invalid_request',
  status: 400,
  statusCode: 400,
  expose: true,
  error_description: 'interaction session not found',
  error_detail: undefined
}```
````